# how to access ServletRequest object in gwt-dispatch ActionHandler<>?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt-dispatch

This may be obvious but I can't see to find my way to the ServletRequest object within a gwt-dispatch ActionHandler.execute() method.

I'm needing to get to the servlet's getRemoteHost() method.

I'm using v1.0 of gwt-dispatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out...

Using guice, inject a Provider into the constructor of the Handler.

```
Provider<HttpServletRequest> servletRequest
```

then in the execute method, use the provider like this...

```
// request ip address
String ipAddress = servletRequest.get().getRemoteAddr();
```